# Convex curves with the axes for asymptotes

Tags: curves

Are all curves in the first quadrant that have the x and y axes for asymptotes convex when viewed from the origin? If not give an example. If yes, how can it be proved?

Answer (score 1):

No. Example:
$$
f(x)=\frac{2+\sin x}{x},\quad x>0.
$$

Comment: What condition can ensure that a curve with the x and y axes for asymptotes is convex?

Comment: There is no special condition for that kind of functions to be convex.